# Getting multiple output from stored procedure using mvc4 razor

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using a stored procedure with mvc4 razor to get two values. I have used below code to get userid and user type. Now how could I make it to return both userid and usertype from stored procedure?

logintable.cs

```
public partial class Userlogintable
{
     public int UserID { get; set; }
     public string Usertypename { get; set; }
     public int Usertype { get; set; }
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public string Username { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
 }
```

homecontroller .cs

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(logintable u)
{
        loginEntitiesdb = new loginEntities();
        int a = db.splogindata(u.Username, u.Password).First().Value;
 //a returns only usertype
        return View(p);
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[splogindata]
    @Username varchar(30),
    @Password varchar(30)
AS
    declare @Userroletype int
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        fullname, userid, usertype 
    FROM
        logintable 
    WHERE
        Username = @Username   
        AND Password = @Password
END
```

Here a returns only usertype which I get from stored procedure. And logintable contains fullname, userid, usertype, password and username columns.

How could I get usertype and userid from table so that values can be stored in parameters and used to pass it to other function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model to represent the data you want to return from the stored procedure:

```
public class MyReturnModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserType { get; set; }
}
```

Then call your stored procedure and use [ObjectContext.Translate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to map the results to your model:

```
public MyReturnModel DoLogin(logintable u)
{
   using (var db = new MyContext())
   {
       var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.CommandText = "splogindata";

      var u = cmd.CreateParameter();
      u.DbType = DbType.String;
      u.ParameterName = "@Username";
      u.Value = u.Username;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(u);

      var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
      p.DbType = DbType.String;
      p.ParameterName = "@Password";
      p.Value = u.Username;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(p);


      db.Database.Connection.Open();
      var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      //  return list as ObjectList
      var results = ((IObjectContextAdapter) db).ObjectContext.Translate<MyReturnModel>(reader);
      //  cast to entity
      var returnModel = (from s in results select s).FirstOrDefault();

      db.Database.Connection.Close();
   }

   return returnModel;
}
```

This is a simplified example and in reality, you'd have a try...catch around the call to `Open`, and the close would be in a `finally` block.

This approach can be used to return multiple record sets (using to ToList() instead of FirstOrDefault), and is also very useful for returning multiple result sets which would otherwise require multiple database calls.

**UPDATE**

To return all the columns from the login table, you need to add the extra properties the 'mapping' model:

```
public string Usertypename { get; set; }
public string FullName { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Obviously you would update the SELECT statement in to stored procedure to match.

Comment: can i return set of values from sp using query like select * from table_name so that required value can be accesesed

Comment: Yes, as long as the model is changed to include all the columns.  Also, you should write the query as `SELECT fullname, userid, usertype, password, username... etc` because if the table was ever changed, `select *` would cause the query to fail.

Comment: i have added model with all columns and changed the query to select in sp now how could i retrieve fullname,userid,usertype from sp in controller.

Comment: here as i am using entityframe work these columns will be added in my model after connecting to model so how could i acces values in controller

Comment: You call the `DoLogin()` method. Look at the return type.